# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) - Where are the synapse configurations located in the latest version?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, apache-synapse

I'm currently using wso2am-4.0.0 and I have been using wso2am-2.1.0 previously.

In the previous version, a synapse configuration xml per each API could be located in the below folder path.

```
<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api
```

But in the latest version, the synapses could not be located in the above mentioned path.

Where can I find the synapse configurations in the latest APIM version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In APIM v4, we maintain these in the memory and we are not writing to the file system.

This is explained here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/synchronizing-artifacts-in-a-gateway-cluster/#inbuilt-artifact-synchronization